# How to access caller Phone Number in Google Dialogflow Phone Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have activated Dialogflow Phone Gateway and anyone can call on my Google number and interact with Dialogflow. I want to access caller number when someone call to my Dialogflow phone number. I have enabled fullfilment using cloud functions for firebase. I want to access caller phone number in cloud function?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 4):

After digging through this example (https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs), I found that `agent.parameters.phone` in the Firebase fulfillment is accessing parameters that were manually gathered, as defined in the json for one of the intents: Line 68: (https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs/blob/master/dialogflow-agent/intents/makeRes.json).

This is standard DialogFlow functionality. It does not represent session metadata, which I think is what you were asking for. As such, the incoming phone number is not accessible.

Comment: However it should be accessable, someone please post this issue in dialogflow repository

Answer (score 0):

> I don't give dialogflow phone number in marketing at all, and I give a
>   twilio phone number and as soon as someone call to that number i note
>   down the caller phone number and redirect call to dialogflow phone
>   number so my customer start talking to dialogflow.

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/285

May be this workaround is for you